# JavaScript: Selecting a part of a text field's content (it must work with older Explorer versions)

Tags: javascript, select, substring, explorer

I need some help to write some JS code. I want to select a substring in a standard HTML input text field. I know the Firefox code, it is really easy, it works fine, look at this:

```
    var_control.selectionStart = var_searchtext.length;
    var_control.selectionEnd   = var_control.value.length;
```

"var_control" is the text field, I defined the variable in the text field by giving "this" to the JS function. As I said it works fine. But ... !!! ... I need the code for older versions of Microsoft Explorer too :-(

I know how I select the whole content of a text field:

```
    var_control.select();
```

But how do I select a part of the field's content?

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

you can `substring` the value to extract to desired value.

```
var str = var_control.select();
str = str.substring(n); // what ever you need
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

For the best browser support I suggest you to use a JS framework like JQuery. If you use JQuery 1.x, it supports IE from IE6. http://jquery.com/browser-support/